# 'Will' twice in one sentence

Tags: word-usage

(1) The government **will** increase funding on school supplies that **will** last until 2023.

Is it wrong to use "will" twice in one sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One *will* is in the main clause, the other is in a relative clause, so why would you think there was any problem using both?

(What you may be thinking of is that English speaker don't usually use *will* in a temporal or conditional clause: *When/if you see him*, not *When/if you will see him*. But that's not what we have here).

However, your sentence doesn't make much sense, because *that will last until 2023* is a restrictive relative clause which qualifies "supplies". So it says that the government will increase funding on certain supplies: which supplies? The supplies that will last until 2023.

If you put a comma before "that", then it will become a non-restrictive relative clause. It will be formally ambiguous whether it qualifies "funding" or "supplies", so it is likely to be interpreted as you meant it.

Answer (score 1):

In informal speaking, non-defining relative clauses are sometimes used to modify a whole clause.

> Some relative clauses refer to a whole clause, a whole sentence, or a longer stretch of language. We always use which to introduce these clauses.
> We often use these clauses in *informal* speaking to express an opinion or evaluation.  [emphasis added]

> I think the other thing that was really good about it as well was that everybody worked really hard and helped tidy up at the end, which I hadn’t expected at all.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses-referring-to-a-whole-sentence)

> The government will increase funding on school supplies that will last until 2023.

As Colin has said, the *will* duplication is not a problem and that *that* currently modifies *supplies*.

Converting the relative clause to a non-defining one may not help as the *which-clause* could still be interpreted as modifying *supplies*, in official use as explained above.

The pronoun *that* has no clear and unique antecedent and, to clear the uncertainty of what the relative clause modifies, we may have to use back the noun *funding*.

> The government will increase funding on school supplies[, and the funding] will last until 2023.

Comment: He could also simply replace "funding *on*" with "funding *for*": "The government will increase funding for school supplies, and that will last until 2023." Though one could also more simply say: "The government will increase funding for school supplies until 2023."